# Connect and retrieve data from SCOPUS database to Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, scopus

I am working with SCOPUS data via API to a Power BI Desktop to retrieve a search of a list of author IDs, but just 25 papers (the first page) out of more than 800 documents were retrieved in the Desktop. This is the [link of SCOPUS API](https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=AU-ID(%2256973530700%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2255911063200%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2236482638800%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%22%C2%A016318706200%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2220433698300%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%22%C2%A07003336314%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2256343679600%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227402141385%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%229743731700%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2236166690800%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%22%C2%A07006406404%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2225521994200%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227005832568%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227003993398%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2257194492913%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2224279923300%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227005533422%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%226603806362%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227003737536%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%2256458722000%22)%20OR%20AU-ID(%227004890330%22)&apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a).

Answer (score 0):

The responses from the API are, by default, limited to 25 results per page.

The top of the Response Body contains details of the results you are receiving, the pertinent details are:

```
"opensearch:totalResults": How many articles your search returned
"opensearch:startIndex": What page of the results you are currently on
"opensearch:itemsPerPage": How many results per page there are.  
"@searchTerms": Your query
"@startPage": What page of the results your query started on (default is 0)
```

In order to receive more than 25 results you will need to include pagination in your requests, by increasing the startPage="0" parameter incrementally.